# XSL count parent node not having a child node with a certain attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file with a certain node ( parentNode in this case ) and I want to know how many specialNode has no childNode having a certain attribute.

Example:

```
<parentNode>
    <specialNode>
        <childNode attrib=true />
        <childNode attrib=false />
    </specialNode>
    <specialNode>
        <childNode attrib=true />
        <childNode attrib=true />
    </specialNode>
    <specialNode>
        <childNode attrib=false />
    </specialNode>
</parentNode>
```

I would like to call something like :

```
<xsl:variable="foo" select="count( not( */specialNode/childNode[ attrib="true" ] ) ) />
```

... and to have foo = 1 because there is only one specialNode where all its child node has attrib = false.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your XML is invalid. attrib=true cannot be, attrib="true" or attrib="false" and you have no end tags

Comment: I'm sorry: forgot the slash. The XML doesn't really matter in fact. The problem's still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count(/parentNode/specialNode[not(childNode[@attrib='true'])])
```

Here is the corrected XML

```
<parentNode>
    <specialNode>
        <childNode attrib="false"/>
        <childNode attrib="false"/>
    </specialNode>
    <specialNode>
        <childNode attrib="true"/>
        <childNode attrib="true"/>
    </specialNode>
    <specialNode>
        <childNode attrib="false"/>
    </specialNode>
</parentNode>
```

Comment: Exactly. The OP is counting "not"'s (ha) and not counting nodes. Count must evaluate to a nodeset to "count" it.